# Make Multiple Copies From Original with image = MiniMagick

Tags: ruby, minimagick

I need to generate several copies of an image in different formats/sizes. Can I do it without re-opening the source for each format/size?

Take this example:

```
# Original image is jpeg
image = MiniMagick::Image.open url
image.crop dimensions
image.format 'pdf'
upload image
# image = MiniMagick::Image.open url # No! Needless network traffic and processing.
image.format 'png'
image.resize new_size
upload image
```

This code is no good without the second `#open` because when `image.format 'png'` is called the image is a PDF, so I would end up rasterizing it, which is not what I want to do.

There's a method `#clone`, but it does not make a clone of the image object. Rather it sets a parameter for the converter. I can't figure out if this will somehow suit my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to do it, which seems fine.

```
# Original image is jpeg
image = MiniMagick::Image.open url
image.crop dimensions

new_image = MiniMagick::Image.open image.tempfile.path

image.format 'pdf'
upload image

new_image.format 'png'
new_image.resize new_size
upload new_image
```

Both the PDF and PNG will be cropped but each will only be converted once.